# Tastypie - Get foreign key resource uri without redundant join query

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm having Trouble figuring out how to get a resource uri of a foreign key without invoking an Extra Join Query to the database.

Let's say I have the following resource:

```
QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    section = fields.ForeignKey(SectionResource,attribute='section')
```

What happens is that tastypie generates an extra Join to the Section table in order to populate the "section" field with data (for example).

BUT, I don't need this extra Join in order to populate this field's value (I need only the resource uri), since I already have it in the Question table (section_id) - All I need to do is prefix the 'section_id' field with 'api/v1/section/'.

I can do something like this:

```
QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    section = fields.IntegerField(attribute='section_id')
```

But I will get **only** the id, **without** the prefix of 'api/v1/section/'

I know I can override dehydrate to do it, But I was wondering if there is a built in way in Tastypie to do it ,  cause it seems like an ugly workaround.

Comment: By default it should give you just the resource uri. What if you try to pass `full=False`?

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining the problem clear enough: I can get the Resource Uri using tastypie, But If I do it as you explained (Or as I did in the first code example), There is by default a redundant join query generated behind the scenes (Which I don't need, Since I only need the resource uri of the section, Which I can get from the Question Table without a join , by taking the section_id field from the **Question table** and prefixing it with "api/v1/section/")

Comment: I don't think there is a built in way to do it.